# MySQL: How to fetch all columns with distinct clause on one column with latest created record

Tags: mysql

I have a DB Table structure

> id, latitude, longitude, altitude, deviceID, createdDate

I am trying to create a query which fetches the  all DISTINCT deviceID which has been created at the latest..

I have tried a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT deviceID
FROM `devicePosition`
ORDER BY createdDate desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on beiller's post, try this solution:

```
SELECT deviceID, createdDate

FROM `devicePosition` outer_dev_pos

WHERE createdDate = (
    select max(inner_dev_pos.createdDate)
    from `devicePosition` inner_dev_pos
    where inner_dev_pos.deviceID = outer_dev_pos.deviceID
)

ORDER BY createdDate desc;
```

**UPDATE:** Explanation:

We are accessing the same table two times in this query, once in the outer select and once in the subselect (the inner select). Therefor, it is necessary to tell in the query which access' deviceID and createdData we mean. This is most important in the where clause of the subselect:

```
where inner_dev_pos.deviceID = outer_dev_pos.deviceID
```

If we didn't use the alias names inner_dev_pos and outer_dev_pos for the two accesses of the same table, this line would read:

```
where deviceID = deviceID
```

which obviously would not make sense.

Comment: what is outer_dev_pos and inner_dev_pos?

Comment: outer_dev_pos is just an alias for the devicePosition table. The table is used twice in the query so it can be helpful to give it a different name each time it is used. Depending on the database that you are using, you might need to put an AS between the table name and alias (e.g. 'devicePosition' AS outer_dev_pos).

Comment: haha thanks for the credit. It is possible to have deviceID, createdDate repeated if two createdDates are in the same microsecond, unlikely but possible, so you may want to add DISTINCT on your select.

Answer (score 1):

Limit can be used in mysql to achieve this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT deviceID, createdDate 
FROM `devicePosition`
ORDER BY createdDate desc 
limit 1
```

Also, you can where clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT deviceID, createdDate 
FROM `devicePosition`
WHERE createdDate = (select max(createdDate) from `devicePosition`)
```

Comment: Although be careful, limit 1 (or SELECT TOP 1 ...) will always return you exactly one result. Putting the logic in the WHERE condition could return you more than one result if 2 or devices happen to share the same created date (which I think is what you want).

Comment: Yes thanks for your additions. It looks like they are looking for the second option, but we can't be sure..... yet :P

Comment: I need to fetch the latest CreatedDATE inside among the same deivceID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(deviceID) FROM `devicePosition` GROUP BY deviceID
```

This will select the latest as max ID is already latest and may be faster as there is not ordering.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going for the pair of deviceID and last createdDate, then use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT deviceID, max(createdDate)
FROM `devicePosition`
GROUP BY deviceID
ORDER BY createdDate desc;
```

This fetches the maximum createdDate **per deviceID**.